# Contradiction between Fourier and Laplace transforms?

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function that has both Fourier and Laplace transforms. Also let $f(t)=0$ for all $t<0$. The Fourier transform of $f$ is
$$\mathcal{F}(\omega)=\mathcal{F}[f](\omega)=\int_0^\infty e^{-2\pi i\omega t}f(t)dt,\;for \;\omega\in\mathbb{R}$$
The Laplace transform of $f$ on the other hand is
$$\mathcal{L}(s)=\mathcal{L}[f](s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt,\;for \;s\in\mathbb{C}$$
If we set $s=2\pi i \omega$. It seems like $\mathcal{F}(\omega)=\mathcal{L}(2\pi i\omega)$ must hold, right? Well, these transforms also have the properties

$$\mathcal{F}\left[f'\right](\omega)=2\pi i\omega\mathcal{F}(\omega)$$
$$\mathcal{L}\left[f'\right](s)=s\mathcal{L}(s)-f(0)$$ 
And once again setting $s=2\pi i\omega$, we have
$$\mathcal{L}\left[f'\right](2\pi i \omega)=2\pi i\omega \mathcal{F}(\omega)-f(0)\neq 2\pi i\omega \mathcal{F}(\omega)$$
Unless $f(0)=0$. Furthermore, 
$$\mathcal{F}\left[f^{(n)}\right](\omega)=(2\pi i\omega)^n\mathcal{F}(\omega)$$
$$\mathcal{L}\left[f^{(n)}\right](s)=s^n\mathcal{L}(s)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} s^{n-k}f^{(k-1)}(0)$$
Which in general (unless $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k<n$) implies
$$\mathcal{L}\left[f^{(n)}\right](2\pi i \omega)\neq \mathcal{F}\left[f^{(n)}\right](\omega)$$ 
And $f^{(n)}(t)$, if $f$ is derivable to the $n^{th}$ order, is nothing but a function, so what the hell?

This really puzzles me, so any answer will be a great contribution to my mental peace, thanks.

Comment: The unilateral Fourier transform doesn't verify $F[f'](w) = 2\pi i w F[f](w)$

Comment: I think in the unilateral Fourier transform, you will have $\mathcal{F}[f'](w) = 2\pi i\omega \mathcal{F}[f](\omega) - f(0)$. To see this, integrate by parts. You will be left with a $f(0)$...

Comment: @moonshine : you should try to re-prove everything when you are in front of such an inconstancy, that's the only way. (and you should forget about the unilateral Laplace transform,  consider instead the bilateral Laplace/Fourier transform of $f(t) 1_{t \ge 0}$)

Comment: I agree with @user1952009 : "unilateral Fourier Transform" is almost inexistant and inconsistant in the huge literature about Fourier Transform.

Comment: @user1952009, I agree with you about the re-prove everything, I'll try to do it, and perhaps answering my own question? Also I included the condition that $f(t)=0$ for all $t<0$ in the question, thanks :)

Comment: Hi all, I know the answer already, user1952009 was right about the prove-it-yourself idea. Do you think I should delete the question, or answer it myself?

Answer (score 4):

Mr. Moonshine, there is no contradiction at all, you just messed it up.

Let me explain. As [Tryss](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/216059/tryss) and [John Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/37200/john-martin) pointed out, the unilateral Fourier transform doesn't indeed has the property
$$\mathcal{F}\left[f^{(n)}\right](\omega)=(2\pi i \omega)^n\mathcal{F}(\omega)$$ but rather
$$\mathcal{F}\left[f^{(n)}\right](\omega)=(2\pi i \omega)^n\mathcal{F}(\omega)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2\pi i\omega)^{n-k}f^{(k-1)}(0)$$

Something that can be checked integrating by parts and using some induction. This matches the property of the unilateral Laplace transform when $s=2\pi i\omega$. But, as [JeanMarie](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305862/jeanmarie) commented, this transform hardly has any relevance because it is never used. So, to describe the situation on the question, the best is to follow the advice of [user1952009](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/user1952009) and do the Fourier and Laplace bilateral transforms of $g(t)=f(t)\theta(t)$, where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside unitary step. Let's remember that 
$$g'(t)=f'(t)\theta(t)+f(t)\delta(t)$$
Where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta. If we take the Laplace transform of $g$,
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[g'\right](s)=\mathcal{L}\left[f'\theta\right](s)+f(0)
$$
$$
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(t)\theta(t)e^{-st}dt+f(0)=I(s)+f(0)
$$
And then do the integral by parts, choosing $du=f'(t)dt$, $u=f(t)$, $v=\theta(t)e^{-st}$ and $dv=e^{-st}\left(\delta(t)-s\theta(t)\right)dt$, we have

$$I(s)=\left[f(t)\theta(t)e^{-st}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\delta(t)e^{-st}dt+s\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\theta(t)e^{-st}dt$$

Substituting back $g$ and the trivial integral with the $\delta$,
$$I(s)=\left[g(t)e^{-s t}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}+s\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-st}dt-f(0)$$

For the transform to exist, we must demand $g(t)e^{-st}$ goes to zero at $\pm\infty$, and hence
$$\mathcal{L}\left[g'\right](s)=s\mathcal{L}\left[g\right](s)$$

The trick here is that in the unilateral Laplace transform property
$$\mathcal{L}\left[f^{(n)}\right](s)=s^n\mathcal{L}(s)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}s^{n-k}f^{(k-1)}(0)$$
Is not applicable to a function like $g(t)=f(t)\theta(t)$ because it requires that the derivatives are defined up to the $n^{th}$ order at $0$, which doesn't hold for $g$.

Summarizing then: either you compare the unilateral Fourier transform with the unilateral Laplace transform, in which case the property of the FT for the derivatives in the question doesn't hold, or you compare bilateral with bilateral, in which case the derivatives property of the Laplace in the question doesn't hold.

I sincerely wish you the return of your mental peace.